# FileInputStream read until last 128 bytes of file

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read the last 128 bytes from a file (the signature) and then trying to read until those bytes but the first part (reading the last 128 bytes) is returning an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
byte[] signature = new byte[128];


        FileInputStream sigFis = new FileInputStream(f);
        sigFis.read(signature, (int)f.length()-128, 128);
        sigFis.close();
```

And then the last part doesn't seem to be working either, I'm using an offset that i increase gradually:

```
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, c);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        int i = cis.read(data);
        int offset = 0, maxsize = (int)f.length()-128;

        while((i != -1) && offset<maxsize){
            fos.write(data, 0, i);
            sig.update(data);
            fos.flush();
            i = cis.read(data);
            offset+=1024;
        }
```

I get an EOFExcpetion with the RAF I used to do my ops...

```
byte[] signature = new byte[128];


            int offset = (int)f.length()-128;

            raf.seek(offset);       

            raf.readFully(signature, 0, 128);
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the damn randomAccessFile I use, I do a seek(file.length()-128) and then read(data, 0, 128) and it just sends an EOFException...

Comment: I was making a dumb mistake, i was reading an empty file...

Answer (score 3):

I would use File or FileChannel to get the file size. This is how to read until the last 128 bytes

```
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("1.txt");
    FileChannel ch = is.getChannel();
    long len = ch.size() - 128;
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    for(long i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int b = bis.read();
        ...
    }
```

if we continue reading we will get the last 128 bytes

```
              ByteArrayOutputStream bout128 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for(int b; (b=bis.read() != -1);) {
                      bout128.write(b);
    }        
              byte[] last128 = bout128.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense, I'll try that out but I think I'm gonna use a RandomAccessFile and the skip the bytes, read the last 128

Comment: Sorry, but this thing is quite particular, won't this use of the stream change the pointer of my FileInputStream (or are you saying I should create a new stream?) and hence screw up the writing of the data?

Comment: If you want only to read from file it's more logical to use FileInputStream. As for RandomAccessFile, if you change file position and then write, it will write from the new position.

Comment: what do you mean "more logical to use FileInputStream"? Because that is exactly what I'm trying to find out, reading the file but stoping it when there are 128 bytes left on the stream/file

Comment: Could you please help on reading until the last 128 bytes but using a fileinputstream?

Comment: Thanks but what you are showing me is how to read everything and then just the last 128, my problem is not that, my probleam lies on reading everything but the last 128 bytes

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused with the read method parameters..

```
    FileInputStream sigFis = new FileInputStream(f);
    sigFis.read(signature, (int)f.length()-128, 128);
    //This doesn't give you last 128 bits. 
    // The offset is offset of the byte array 'signature
    // Thats the reason you see ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    sigFis.close();
```

replace your read() method with

```
  sigFis.read(signature);
  //But now signature cannot be just 128 array but length of file. And read the last 128 bytes
```

InputStream read method signature looks as below:

```
  int java.io.FileInputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len) 
  Parameters:
  b the buffer into which the data is read.
  off the start offset in the destination array b
  len the maximum number of bytes read.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helps and a lot, what a stupid mistake I was making, that's what you get for not reading the method properties with propper attention... Thanks a lot. I'm going to use a RandomAccessFile since I also want to trim it to a specific size to remove the signature, so, I can skip(file.length()-128) and then read(data).